# volume mounts preventing startup in container

Tags: docker, cassandra

I am able to start Cassandra in a docker container fine, but when I add a *volume mount* to the run command, Cassandra won't start and hangs.  I am using the official latest Apache Cassandra image (v 3.10), running Docker version 17.04.0-ce.

This starts ok:

```
docker run -d -P --name=cassandra --net=host cassandra
```

This hangs:

```
docker run -P -v /home/joe/apache-cassandra/data:/var/lib/cassandra --name=cassandra --net=host cassandra
```

When it hangs, the last line in the Cassandra log is:

```
INFO  [main] 2017-05-29 16:16:48,567 ColumnFamilyStore.java:406 - Initializing system.IndexInfo
```

I suspect it's a permission problem, so here's what the permissions look like for the host directory

```
/home/joe/apache-cassandra/data:

0 drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 May 29 14:36 commitlog 
0 drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 May 29 14:36 data 
0 drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 May 29 12:14 hints 
0 drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0 May 29 12:44 saved_caches
```

When the container runs without the volume mount, I notice the equivalent directories within the container are owned by "cassandra" and not "vboxsf".

Any idea how to fix the issue?

- Joe

Answer (score 0):

To "fix" this issue, run your container with another path, such as /data-cassandra

The problem is your /home/joe/apache-cassandra/data is mount from your vbox host. Docker can't change owner or permission of this.

Comment: Thanks a ton benjah1!  As you suspected, that did the trick ... thanks again.